# Responsive CSS Grid with large center image

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm looking to create a 5 column CSS grid layout. The content will be populated by the client's CMS, so i'm hoping to use a repeat function so more content can be added as necessary. The difficulty i'm having however, is adding a large, centered image `grid-row: 2/3` and `grid-column: 2-4`. The ideal design looks like this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBQzvV

This isn't a great solution however, as the fixed pixel widths ruin responsiveness, and forced image dimensions. Is there a way to create this CSS Grid with a centered larger image, without forced pixel dimensions, that also doesn't leave a gap? Or do I need to pull in Isotope here

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Copied from your pen. Just change height to 100%

```
img:nth-child(6), img:nth-child(7) {
  height: 100%;
}
```